# InfluxDB Cloud and Thingsboard

Tags: influxdb, thingsboard

Our IoT data is in influxDB cloud.
I hope to use Thingsboard.
Can I retrieve data from influx DB to Thingsboard?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no native integration between ThingsBoard and influxDB. You would have to write your own microservice for fetching the data of influxDB and forwarding it to ThingsBoard e.g. via HTTP, MQTT or Kafka.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/api/

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/

Alternatively, you could use low-code tools like Node-RED for this purpose.